# VB6 - can't always read full line from CSV file

Tags: csv, vb6

I have problems reading a semikolon separated CSV file, line by line.

It looks like this:

**Headline**
ID;Name;Lastname;Street;Comment

**Dataline**
123;Gary;Miller;Mystreet 123;"This is a comment"

This is my code:

```
Set tsFile = cFiFo.FileSysObj.OpenTextFile(sCSVPath, ForReading)

While Not tsFile.AtEndOfStream
        sLine = tsFile.ReadLine
        sLine = Replace(sLine, """", "")
        Call AddImportLine(sLine, iLinesErr, iLinesOK)
Wend
```

This is what I get at some point (it mostly works). Something has to be wrong with the line. I wasn't able to see a line break, wether in a text editor nor in excel.

Wrong output from sLine 1:
123;Gary;Miller;Mystreet 123;This is

Wrong output from sLine 2:
 a comment

What could I do?

Thanks in advance

Xyron

**Solution:**

```
Set tsFile = cFiFo.FileSysObj.OpenTextFile(sCSVPath, ForReading)

sFile = tsFile.ReadAll
'Replacing all CarrigeReturn-LineFeeds with a placeholder (to make sure, that CarrigeReturn-LineFeeds being kept that way)
sFile = Replace(sFile, vbCrLf, "#^CRLF^#")
sFile = Replace(sFile, vbLf, "#^LF^#")
sFile = Replace(sFile, "#^CRLF^#", vbCrLf)
tsFile.Close

'Overwrite existing File
Set tsFile = cFiFo.FileSysObj.OpenTextFile(sCSVPath, ForWriting)
tsFile.Write (sFile)
tsFile.Close

'Reading
Set tsFile = cFiFo.FileSysObj.OpenTextFile(sCSVPath, ForReading)

While Not tsFile.AtEndOfStream
    sLine = tsFile.ReadLine
    sLine = Replace(sLine, """", "")
    Call AddImportLine(sLine, iLinesErr, iLinesOK)
Wend
```

Thanks for your awesome help!

Comment: Try using ADO instead. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms974559.aspx

Comment: Notepad++ and use the Show Whitespace option. That will help you determine if there is an odd character in that line. You could do it programatically, but that seems like a waste of time.

Comment: some ideas, the file may be Unicode, or UTF8, or something, use an editor that displays binary to se

Comment: An idea: to better debug this, make a copy of the csv file read it in whole and Replace(CsvFileContent,VBCRLF,"%")  ------- This should then replace all line breaks with % to help you better debug the file. regardless, i myself hate the FileSystemObject and preffer using the old 'Open for input' kinda way. might wana try that see how it goes

Comment: The FSO's `ReadLine` will treat a naked `LF` as a newline symbol, so most likely that's what is going on.  While it won't make the problem go away I'd also recommended throwing the FSO as far away from you as possible.  Native Text I/O (i.e. `Line Input #`) will treat a naked `CR` as a newline but not a naked `LF`.

Comment: Xyron, are you looking for a way to process just *this* particular file, or do you need a method for importing this and future files which might have a line break character in the comments column?

Comment: I was looking for a way to import this particular file.

I solved my problem by replacing the linefeeds (vbLf) by a placeholder. And I replaced my placeholder later on, with the linefeeds again.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't find a way to view and delete whatever character is causing you problems, you might try a manual scrub.  The following code only allows ASCII character 32 to 126, and also removes the double quotes.

```
  Dim ss() As String = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(fileName)
  For Each s As String In ss
       Dim sb As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder
       For Each c As Char In s
           Dim i As Integer = CType(c,Integer)
           If ((i >= 32)  _
                       AndAlso ((i <= 126)  _
                       AndAlso (i <> 34))) Then
               sb.Append(c)
           End If
       Next
       Dim sLine As String = sb.ToString
       AddImportLine(sLine, iLinesErr, iLinesOK);
  Next
```

If the ReadAllLines doesn't separate your lines into strings the way you want it to, you probably have a rogue CR or line feed character in there.  You could run the first part of your file through this sample ascii displayer to see what the ascii code of your junk character is.

```
Private Sub DisplayFileAsAscii(ByVal fileName As String, ByVal numChars As Integer, ByVal includeText As Boolean)
     Dim sb As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder
     Dim MyFile As FileInfo = New FileInfo(fileName)
     Dim sr As StreamReader = MyFile.OpenText
     'Read a single character.
     Dim FirstChar As Integer = sr.Read

     While (FirstChar <> 0)
         sb.Append(("[" + FirstChar.ToString))
         If includeText Then
             sb.Append(("~" + CType(FirstChar,Char).ToString))
         End If
         sb.Append("]")
         FirstChar = sr.Read
         numChars = (numChars - 1)
         If (numChars < 0) Then
             Exit While
         End If

     End While
     MessageBox.Show(sb.ToString)
 End Sub
```

Comment: That looks like a .NET solution

Comment: Oops, you're right.  It has been so long since I'd done VB6...  Still, the filtering idea would work if nothing else would.  Just read character by character and only keep the characters that you want.

Answer (score 0):

If using notepad to write it copy and paste into wordpad to check line breaks. Notepad totally ignores and hides carriage returns but other programs don't. Notepad only looks for line feeds.

In Notepad, CR while invisible, do require two presses of the arrow keys to move the text caret.

If coping from browser based documentation such as web pages and help systems sometimes stray carriage returns get invisibly inserted in notepad.

### .